# How to run private node on EthereumJ

Tags: ethereumj

I would like to run a private node on EthereumJ. I don't know how to start mining on EthereumJ and how to start EthereumJ node. I will be very grateful if someone tell me where to start looking (documentation or code) in EthereumJ.